# Insert equally spaced values between consecutive values of an existing matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working in **matlab**. I have a **row vector** `in` and a scalar variable `no_step` indicating step size. For each `i = 1:size(in,2)-1` ,I want to insert `no_step` equally spaced values between `in(1,i) and in(1,i+1)` and generate a new matrix `out`. In other words, I want to implement the following loop without using loop.

NOTE : - It is assured that `1/no_step` is a *terminating decimal* .

```
n = size(in,2);
new_n = n+no_step*(n-1);
out  = zeros(1,new_n);
k = 1;
for i = 1:n-1
    temp = (in(1,i+1) - in(1,i))/no_step;
    temp2 = in(1,i):temp:(in(1,i+1) - temp);
    out(1,k:k+no_step) = temp2;
    k =k+no_step+1;
end
out(new_n) = in(n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
out = interp1(1:numel(in), in, 1:1/no_step:numel(in));
```

Example:

```
>> in = [2 3 5 9];
>> no_step = 2;
>> out = interp1(1:numel(in), in, 1:1/no_step:numel(in))
out =
    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    7.0000    9.0000
```